# How to display a server's certificate when the cert is signed by an unknown CA?

Tags: postgresql, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I have a server that is giving me TLS problems and I would like to view the cert it is presenting in order to help diagnose the issue. Normally, I would use openssl to display the cert like so:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect facebook.com:443
```

However, I don't know what CA signed this server's cert. I *thought* it was our internal CA but testing suggests otherwise. Thus I cannot use openssl's `-CAfile` or `-CApath` flags to specify the CA.

One more restriction. The server is not an HTTP server (it's postgres), otherwise I would just use `curl --insecure`.

I tried using the `-verify` flag because according to [OpenSSL's documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/s_client.html):

> The verify depth to use. This specifies the maximum length of the server certificate chain and turns on server certificate verification. Currently the verify operation continues after errors so all the problems with a certificate chain can be seen. As a side effect the connection will never fail due to a server certificate verify failure.

It claims to continue after all errors so all problems can be seen. However, all I get is:

```
1737:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:188:
```

That is the error message I get with or without `-verify`.

So how can I view the certificate presented by the server?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Your use of the OpenSSL command is probably wrong. It lacks TLS and SNI. To answer your question about the commands to view the server's certificate: `openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port> -tls1 -servername <hostname> | openssl x509 -text -noout`

Comment: `-servername` doesn't appear to be a valid option in my openssl version (OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008), which I have no control over.